# How to layout Firebase database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to know how to layout a Firebase database so I can easily get Data about coordinates. (Only started using Firebase yesterday so am very very new to it)

**ViewController**

```
var reference: DatabaseReference!
var handle: DatabaseHandle?
```

**viewDidLoad**

```
reference = Database.database().reference()
handle = ref.child("Places/America/Capital/Washington/Coordinates").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in 
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let theSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
        let theValue = theSnap.value as! Double
        print(theValue)
    }
```

This prints the coordinates perfectly. But is there any way I can get all the coordinates in my Database? Am I laying out the Database wrong or what syntax should I use in order to get all data that has latitude and longitude in it?

**Image of Firebase Database**

[image]

***edit 1***
Is there no easy way of doing a for-in loop instead of just copying the handle line and changing the necessary file path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are so very close.

The path you specified (the Firebase Reference) is for a specific set of coordinates at a coordinate node. You then iterate over the two child nodes within Coordinates which prints the latitude and longitude child nodes.

If you want to get the coords for all, you need to go up a few levels and use the same technique to iterate over the child nodes.

It's a bit hard to wrap your brain around at first so let me give you a leg up. Here's the complete code and the output. Note that I stored the coords as int's so adjust accordingly. I would probably suggest storing them as strings.

```
let placesRef = self.ref.child("Places")
placesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    for countryChild in snapshot.children { //iterate over each country
        let countryChildSnap = countryChild as! DataSnapshot //cast the child to a snapshot
        let countryName = countryChildSnap.key //get it's key, the country name
        print("country: \(countryName)")
        let capitalSnap = countryChildSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "Capital") //get the nodes within the capital node
        for stateChild in capitalSnap.children { //iterate over each state within the country
            let stateChildSnap = stateChild as! DataSnapshot
            let stateName = stateChildSnap.key
            print("  state: \(stateName)")
            let coordsSnap = stateChildSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "Coordinates")
            let lat = coordsSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "latitude").value as! Int
            let lon = coordsSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "longitude").value as! Int
            print("    latitude: \(lat)  longitude: \(lon)")
        }
    }
})
```

and the output

```
country: America
  state: Washington
    latitude: 38  longitude: -77
country: France
  state: Paris
    latitude: 48  longitude: 2
country: Germany
  state: Berlin
    latitude: 52  longitude: 13
```

Note that I only want to read this once so I am using .observeSingleEvent. If you want to be notified of future changes, leverage .observe with .childAdded, .childChanged and .childRemoved.

Comment: Honestly can't thank you enough, been tearing my hair out all day trying to find helpful information with no avail! Really helpfully laid out too, so thank you! Can you suggest any good places to get information about using Firebase for someone who's new to Firebase and Databases/JSONs?

Comment: @Txo Glad it helped! I would suggest reading [NOSQL DATA MODELING TECHNIQUES](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) as well as [Structuring your Firebase](https://www.airpair.com/firebase/posts/structuring-your-firebase-data) and take a look at this old post [Arrays Are Evil](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) because people new to NoSQL frequently fall into the "array pit of doom" and do a lot of backtracking instead of avoiding them in the first place.